# How open a jpg in numpy?

Tags: image, url, numpy, urllib2

I want to load a jpg image from a url as a numpy array. But whenenver I do, I get an error.  Can someone tell me what I can do to make my code work?

```
import urllib2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f=urllib2.urlopen("https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USA/USA-EF-Defeat/maps/USA-EF-Defeat-40.jpg")
print(f.shape)
plt.imshow(f)
plt.show()
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way, is to Use `PIL` to load JPG image

```
import urllib2
import cStringIO
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline


url='https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USA/USA-EF-Defeat/maps/USA-EF-Defeat-40.jpg'
im = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()))
plt.imshow(im, cmap='Greys_r')
```

or use `plt.imread` with `format=` to have image in numpy format directly.

```
im = plt.imread(urllib2.urlopen(url), format='jpeg')
# or using `io.BytesIO`
# im = plt.imread(io.BytesIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read()), format='jpeg')
plt.imshow(im, cmap='Greys_r')
```

Comment: But the OP asked how to open the image in numpy

Answer (score 1):

`urllib` is for html file. For images you need an `imread` tool.

Natively `plt.imread` only open `PNG` files.

For `JPG` file you can use PIL or Pillow for python 3, which is an image processing module. For only io concern, [imageio](http://imageio.github.io/) is a modern easy to install alternative:

```
im = imageio.imread('https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/
USA/USA-EF-Defeat/maps/USA-EF-Defeat-40.jpg')
```

Comment: I don't know if this was true when it was posted, but it is no longer the case. You can read non-PNG files, e.g. JPEG and GIF, with Matplotlib's `plt.imread()`.